# Intepreting held down keys

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I am building a `Raspberry Pi` rover written in Python and I am looking to control the rover via `SSH`. Hence, I would run the script and then want the rover to move in the directions provided by me in real-time, like an RC car (think key up, key down, key left, key right).

I read online that one of the possibilities might be to use the `pygame.key.get_pressed()` function, but this is not working in my shell. When I run that command in my `raspberry pi` python shell, I only receive a tuple of zeros that times out after a fraction of a second.

My code is the following:

```
speed = input('How fast do you want the rover to go? Give a value lower than 1: ')

while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
    if keys == True:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            fwd(speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            bwd(speed)
    if keys == False:
        MS.motor1off
        MS.motor2off
```

with `fwd` and `bwd` being functions that activate the motors in the forward and backward directions.

When I run the script, it goes through the loop fine, but the motors do not respond to the key being held. When I added a print statement, I noticed that this was also not printed onto the console.

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed with this, please?

Comment: Try printing `keys` right after the `keys=` line. It will never be `True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a pygame expert and have never used `key.get_pressed()` method. I use `event.get()` which works well. Here is a minimum example of the code I use:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 250
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 120

pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                print('works!')
```

You must to make sure, that you initialize pygame and also create a window AND the window must be in the focus. Then it will work. If this is not convenient for you, then you have to hook into the keypress event of your keyboard so that you get the global keypress, no matter what window is in focus.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list of booleans which represent the state of the keys. A list can never be equal to `True` or `False` so the code in your `if keys == True:` and `if keys == False:` clauses will never be executed.

So just get rid of these `if` clauses and use an `else` clause after `if keys[pygame.K_UP]:` or both statements to turn the motor off (not sure what exactly you want to do).

```
while True:
    # You must make a call to the event queue every frame or the window will "freeze".
    pygame.event.pump()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        fwd(speed)
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bwd(speed)
    else:  # No key pressed.
        MS.motor1off
        MS.motor2off
```

By the way, if `motor1off` and `motor2off` are methods, you probably want to call them:  `MS.motor1off()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, in the end I used both of your codes (I had not added the pygame display), so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From `@WurzelseppQX`*'s* code , I have made a new code that prints a text as long as the button is kept pressed and will stop printing when the button is released. Here is the code:

```
import pygame  #importing pygame

pygame.init() #initializing pygame

width = 100 # width of window
height = 100 #height of window

pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) # setting dimensions

while True:
    tbreak = False # to break two loops
    for event in pygame.event.get():   #getting events     
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #see if a button is pressed
            if event.key == pygame.K_w: # if button is 'W' then
                while True: # making loop
                    print("Key 'W' pressed") 
                    ev = pygame.event.get() #getting events to see if the user just released the key
                    for e in ev: #looping the events
                        if e.type == pygame.KEYUP: #if any key is released
                            #You can also set specific keys
                            tbreak = True #to break the outerloop
                            break #breaking the inner loop
                    if tbreak == True:break #breaking
```

Now the above code blocks the rest of your game when the button is pressed. If you don't want your code to do this then use the following code:

```
global topass
topass = 0
def on_press(): #what to do on button press
    global topass
    print("Key 'W' pressed")
    topass = 1
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    if len(events) == 0 and topass == 1:on_press()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w or topass == 1:
                on_press()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                topass = 0
```

Comment: This suggestion is not good. The second `while` loop blocks the execution of the main `while` loop.

Comment: @skrx I don't agree with it. I am sure that you have not tested my code. If you add a `print` statement in the main loop ,  then you will see it printing until a button isn't pressed.

Comment: I've tested the code, the second while loop blocks the rest of the game.

Comment: @skrx It probably will , but only when the button is kept pressed. If the button is not pressed then it will not block the rest of the game.

Comment: @skrx I have added another code which in addition to printing till the button is pressed also runs the rest of the game.